is it possible to determine which Chrome tabs are using the most energy, using a [shell] script?
This answer describes a two-step process of determining which tabs are utilizing the most energy on MacOS, but is achievable on any Linux based system (that I know of) using htop or similar in place of Activity Monitor.
I’d like to instead have a script that I can run, which just spits out the top N CPU-hogging (i.e. that have consumed the most CPU time, not the ones using the most CPU right now) tabs. I could then run this automatically, should a tab get too greedy, manually, or like a cool kid via Raycast.
I tried sifting through the output from hitting l in htop on a hoggish tab (which runs lsof under the hood) to no avail. All I could glean from the output was which Profile the tab belonged to really. I took a look at dtrace and dtruss but they don’t seem like the right avenue.
Anyone have any ideas?
